# print all values in array from loop in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array created from loop which is returning the correct data

```
$ku = array();
    $oid = array('id-ce-keyUsage');
    if(isset($chain['tbsCertificate']['extensions'])) {
        $count = count($chain['tbsCertificate']['extensions']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $count2 = count($chain['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$i]['extnValue']);
            for($j = 0; $j < $count2; $j++) {
                if(array_key_exists('extnId', $chain['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$i]) &&
                in_array($chain['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$i]['extnId'], $oid)) {
                $value = $chain['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$i]['extnValue'][$j];
                $ku[] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
print_r($ku);
```

The above code produces this, which is correct.

```
Array
(
    [0] => keyEncipherment
    [1] => digitalSignature
)
Array
(
    [0] => cRLSign
    [1] => keyCertSign
)
Array
(
    [0] => cRLSign
    [1] => keyCertSign
)
```

However, I would like to be able to print the values of `$ku` on their own, like so:

```
keyEncipherment, digitalSignature
cRLSign, keyCertSign
cRLSign, keyCertSign
```

I tried the following code but the results, and although the results look accurate, its actually adding the results of each iteration together rather then keeping them separate.

Here is the code im trying:

```
foreach ($ku as $val) {
    $temp[] = "$val";
    $key_usage = implode(', ', $temp);
    }
    echo $key_usage;
```

and here is the result:

```
keyEncipherment, digitalSignature
keyEncipherment, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign
keyEncipherment, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign, cRLSign, keyCertSign
```

Would appreciate some assistance. Happy to share more code if needed.

-UPDATE-

This code seems to help but hoping to find a better solution where i can just echo a string without []

```
$len=count($ku);
    for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
    echo $ku[$i].', ';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store value in to another array, as your value is array itself.

After the discussion in chat:

```
 $new_ku = implode(',',$ku); 
 echo $new_ku;
```

Comment: i get this error `Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\getcertdetails2\get_cert16.php on line 737` this line is `$key_usage[] = implode(',', $val);`

Comment: Also, i need a solution that uses echo instead of print_r as i will be using it as part of html code

Comment: you can echo in loop , if it is your requirement.

Comment: thx but still getting the above mentioned error.. i wonder if there is an issue because i have foreach within foreach.. can you see the full code here? http://www.pastebin.ca/3010376 - the lines in question are 154 to 156

Comment: with your latest solution, i am getting this warning: `Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\getcertdetails2\get_cert16.php on line 737`

Comment: line 737 is equal to line 155 in the pastebin i provided to you

Comment: @user3436467 can you dump $val in loop and let me know what it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78735/discussion-between-zan-and-user3436467).

Comment: i updated my post with a solution which seems to work but i need something where i can echo a single string without any [] - let me know if we can build off that or if you still want the dump ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
array_walk($ku, create_function('$k, $v', 'echo $v[0].", ".$v[1];'));
```

If you have PHP version >= 5.3 then you can use..

```
array_walk($ku, function($i, $v){ echo $v[0].", ".$v[1]; });
```

Comment: `create_function()` should really not be used anymore.

Comment: @Ja͢ck it's has security issue but supported in older PHP versions, `OP` can use modern callback function...

Comment: And by old you probably mean *ancient*! 5.3 was released in 2009.